# Apache Netbeans 11.3 could not run web maven projects under Apache Tomee(plume, microprofile, plus)

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-tomee, tomee-8

Recently I have big problem, Netbeans could not run any web/maven project under TomEE.
Just create simple maven web project and run. TomEE server start but unable to deploy WAR.
Then you run TomEE from console and build WAR and copy to TomEE/webapps, it works.
JDK version is no matter, I have JDK 1.8 and 11.
From first run TomEE go to background and run as a separated thread.
Redeploy and rebuild does not help, you must restart netbeans, kill all java processes.
Installed all latest version of netbeans. 
My OS Ubuntu Linux, my coworkers also have the same problem, this problem starts from last week.

Answer (score 0):

all problem solved by installing apache netbeans 12